# The scanner will not take in the input so it cant process it

Tags: java, input

This class runs but when I type something into the scanner nothing happens. It's supposed to have the input be registered and ran through another class where I then get the response and try to print it.

```
public class Eliza {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "";
        String response = "";
        ElizaResponder responder = new ElizaResponder();

        System.out.println("Welcome to Christian Rebelo's Eliza");
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println("ELIZA> " + responder.getGreeting());

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (responder.isNotFinished()) {
            line = s.nextLine();
        }

        response = responder.getResponse(line);
        System.out.println(response);

        System.out.println("ELIZA> " + responder.getFarewell());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of your relevant code here?

Comment: Yeah, what does the `ElizaResponder` class do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the comments it looks like this:

```
while (responder.isNotFinished()) {
    line = s.nextLine();
}
    response = responder.getResponse(line);
    System.out.println(response);
```

is suppposed to be this:

```
while (responder.isNotFinished()) {
    line = s.nextLine();

    response = responder.getResponse(line);
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
while (responder.isNotFinished()) {
        line = s.nextLine();
}
```

will read either no lines at all, or infinitely many without ever doing anything with the input.